# Creating dynamic matrix for every element in a batch in TensorFlow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am working on a siamese CNN with attention in TensorFlow.

The CNN structure consists on a embedding lookup table shared by two CNN sharing weights. 
The inputs for the network are two matrices, both containing indices for question and answer to be fed into the network (batch_size x sentence_length):

```
self.input_q = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sentence_length], name="input_q")
self.input_a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sentence_length], name="input_a")
```

After embedding each sentence (row from the input matrix) I end up with two tensors (questions and answer) each of them of size: batch_size x sentence_lentgh x embedding_size.

Let's forget for now about the batch dimension to make things easier. This is to say, we have two matrices Qemb and Aemb, both **sentence_lentgh x embedding_size**. 
From this two matrices I would like to construct a third one, an attention matrix **A** used for a posterior learnable attention feature matrix , using numpy would be defined as follows:

```
A[i,j] = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.linalg.norm(Qemb[i,:]-Aemb[j,:]))
```

This matrix is built for each input pair, so should be a part of the graph, but apparently this cannot be done in TensorFlow as there's no **asingn** operation by index for a Tensor. 
Am I right?
I thought I could run the ops for embedding the question and answer, build the A matrix outside the graph given the computedembeddings and then feed the A matrix back to the graph to continue the next operations based on it.

```
self.attention_matrix = \
   tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                  [None, sentence_length, sentence_length], 
                  name = "Attention_matrix")
```

Is there any problem with this approach that I might not be aware of?
(Appart from runing the embeddings ops twice, what doesn't seem optimal, but not a big deal)

Comment: Tensors are immutable but you can assign to variables by index, ie `sess.run(a[0,0].assign(2))`. However, this not very efficient, typically the approach is to use matrix tricks to turn things into a matrix expression rather than nested loops

Comment: Thx @YaroslavBulatov, I'll try to figure out how to get this without looping over the indices.
On the other hand, is there any reason to avoid running the embedding ops and outside the graph computations compute this matrix or any other thing and then feed back to the graph to cntinue? Anything I am not aware of?

Comment: main reason is that your "outside of Tensorflow" won't run on GPU. Also, it'll double allocate memory for some objects (the numpy copy and tensorflow copy)